# Google Maps won't load. Grey box. Then after some time it loads

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

It was working fine, I have no idea what happened.

I load the map using a custom knockout.js binding. It shows a grey area which is interactive as if the map was there, but there is no map. If I just let it sit, eventually this error is thrown "Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided." in Chrome, or this one in Firefox: "Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement".

Afterwhich the map loads as normal.

Any ideas?

Here's the binding:

```
        ko.bindingHandlers.iMap = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor()();
            var lat_lon = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat(),value.lon());

            if(!value.map){
                var styles = [
                   {
                     featureType: "poi",
                     stylers: [
                      { visibility: "off" }
                     ]   
                    },
                   {
                     featureType: "transit",
                     stylers: [
                      { visibility: "off" }
                     ]   
                    }                        
                ];

                var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,{name: "Styled Map"});                    
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: lat_lon,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                      mapTypeIds: []
                    },
                };   
                value.map = new google.maps.Map(element,mapOptions);
                value.map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
                if(value.legit_data){
                    value.setMarker();
                }
                value.map.setMapTypeId('map_style');                    
                google.maps.event.addListener(value.map, 'click', function(event){ value.clickEvent(event) });     
            }

            value.map.setCenter(lat_lon);
        }
    };
```

Here is the initializer:

```
        function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_WOULD_BE_HERE&sensor=false&' +
        'callback=initialize';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }    

    window.onload = loadScript;  

    function initialize() {
        viewmodel = new viewModel();     
        ko.applyBindings(viewmodel); 
    }
```

Managed to grab the error too:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided. VM2835:37
(anonymous function) VM2835:37
RP.(anonymous function).A.RP.(anonymous function).F VM2835:37
IP VM2835:31
a.j VM2835:31
wf.(anonymous function).ka main.js:24
b.j VM2835:31
wf.(anonymous function).ka main.js:24
PP.(anonymous function).md VM2835:36
(anonymous function) VM2835:35
(anonymous function) main.js:25
(anonymous function) VM2835:35
(anonymous function) VM2835:25
Wv.(anonymous function).H VM2832:90
(anonymous function) main.js:11
(anonymous function) VM2832:90
(anonymous function) VM2832:89
(anonymous function) VM2832:90
(anonymous function) main.js:12
```

Comment: Sorry Andrew, I should have added that to begin with.